# Use async await in forEach loop, node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async-await

I had a problem when I tried to use `forEach` that contained `await` inside the loop, so I need to define the `async` in front of the `forEach` loop and it returned the error.

```
exports.filterAverageRatingsEachSkillForStudent = async (req, res) => {
  let receiver = req.query.receiver;
  let result = [];
  try {
    console.log('receiver id', receiver);

    for (let id of receiver) {
      console.log('Query String ', id);
      const findRating = await FeedbackSchema.find({
        receiver: id,
        //will add level query later
      }).select('ratingL ratingS ratingR ratingW');
      console.log('Rating Length', findRating.length);
      let totalSpeaking = 0;
      let totalWriting = 0;
      let totalListening = 0;
      let totalReading = 0;
      let lengthS = findRating.length;
      let lengthR = findRating.length;
      let lengthL = findRating.length;
      let lengthW = findRating.length;

      findRating.forEach((rating) => {
        console.log('Speaking star = ', rating.ratingS);
        totalSpeaking += rating.ratingS;
      });
      console.log('Total speaking', totalSpeaking);
      console.log('lengthS = ', lengthS);
      let highestS = lengthS * 5;
      let resultOfSpeakingRate = (totalSpeaking * 5) / highestS;
      console.log('Average Speaking Rate ---> ', resultOfSpeakingRate);

      findRating.forEach((rating) => {
        totalWriting += rating.ratingW;
      });
      let highestW = lengthW * 5;
      let resultOfWritingRate = (totalWriting * 5) / highestW;

      findRating.forEach((rating) => {
        totalReading += rating.ratingR;
      });
      let highestR = lengthR * 5;
      let resultOfReadingRate = (totalReading * 5) / highestR;

      findRating.forEach((rating) => {
        totalListening += rating.ratingL;
      });
      let highestL = lengthL * 5;
      let resultOfListeningRate = (totalListening * 5) / highestL;
      
      res.json({
        writing: resultOfWritingRate,
        speaking: resultOfSpeakingRate,
        listening: resultOfListeningRate,
        reading: resultOfReadingRate,
      });
    }
    //return res.json(totalRating);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

Error, able to solve the async await error but still return me only one response result and after that, it showed `cannot sent header`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.forEach()` is not async-aware.  Use a plain `for/of` loop instead.  In fact, pretty much stop using `.forEach()` entirely these days as its basically obsolete.  With block scope available now with `let` and `const`, there is no reason to use `.forEach()` and it's extra function scope any more.  Use a regular `for` loop instead.

You can fix this particular code by changing to this:

```
exports.filterAverageRatingsEachSkillForStudent = async (req, res) => {
    let receiver = req.query.receiver; //array of id ['ABBd23', 'SDSd242', 'dfNJ47']
    try {
        console.log('receiver id', receiver);

        for (let id of reciever) {
            console.log('Query String ', id);
            const findRating = await FeedbackSchema.find({
                receiver: id,
            }).select('ratingL ratingS ratingR ratingW');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

It also appears that you must not have disclosed all the code for this function because it looks like you're trying to get `findRating`, but then you never do anything with it.

The error you report about cannot set headers after they are sent does not occur in this code since that error is about sending multiple responses to the same incoming request and you don't send any responses in this code.  So, help with that particular error would require disclosing more code or perhaps fixing this function will also fix that (we can't tell since we can't see the code that actually causes that error).

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, I update the full following code above, please check it, and I was able to remove the async await error by using for loop, but I still get the error said, cannot set headers after they sent to client.... and it also return only the first response id when check with postman. it suppose to response with array of objects.

Comment: @Jonh - Now that you're showing the whole function body, you have `res.json()` INSIDE a `for` loop.  What do you expect that to do?  It's going to attempt to send multiple responses, but you can't do that - that's what causes the cannot set headers error.  Accumulate your results in an array and send one response with the array after the loop.  You're still using `.forEach()` too in other places.  I'm serious that you should get rid of it.  It's obsolete now - no reason to create extra functions just to run a loop.

Comment: the goal is, I want to return the whole array of objects `[{
    "writing": 4.183333333333334,
    "speaking": 3.866666666666667,
    "listening": 4,
    "reading": 4.2
}, {
    "writing": 4.183333333333334,
    "speaking": 3.866666666666667,
    "listening": 4,
    "reading": 4.2
}]` after finishing all the for loop, should I create a empty array=[] and push the result of each iteration to that array? how can I achieve that? Sorry, just want to make it clear for you.

Comment: @Jonh - I'm trying to avoid writing code for you again (since you didn't disclose the whole problem initially).  Can't you just declare an array before you loop, `.push()` results into that array in your loop and then after the loop send the array you just built?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, and now I am able to retrieve the array of object by pushing those objects to the new array. Thank you very much for your time. Once again, thank you for your explanation 

Comment: @Jonh - OK, glad you got it implemented and working.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of Promise.all() if there is no dependency between each iteration. Here is the example -

```
exports.filterAverageRatingsEachSkillForStudent = async (req, res) => {
  let receiver = req.query.receiver; //array of id ['ABBd23', 'SDSd242', 'dfNJ47']
  try {
    console.log('receiver id', receiver);
    let results = await Promise.all(receiver.map(async (id) => {
      console.log('Query String ', id);
      return FeedbackSchema.find({
        receiver: id,
      }).select('ratingL ratingS ratingR ratingW'); 
   });
   console.log(results) // this will be an array of results
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
```